# UICollectionView Not Responding to Touch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to programmatically draw my CollectionView from within a custom class that subclasses UIView.  The app loads up with no errors and the CollectionView is being drawn correctly as I can see the cell items, but the CollectionView does not respond to touch.  When I try to scroll nothing happens.

I inspected the ViewController using the Debug View Hierarchy button in Xcode to see if there was possibly a view on top.  There was not and I could see the cells clearly drawn separately.

Class:

```
class DrawUI_mainCollectionView : UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
            
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    var collectionView : UICollectionView?
    
    private func setup() {
        
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(kScreenWidth),height: 137)
        
        let offset = 120.0
        let collectionViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offset, width: Double(kScreenWidth), height: Double(kScreenHeight))
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: collectionViewFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "MealCategoryCell", bundle:Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.addSubview(self.collectionView!)
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MealCategoryCell
        cell.label.text = "test"
        cell.textDescription.text = "textDescription"
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: kScreenWidth, height: 137)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("cell \(indexPath.row)")
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("no storyboard...")
    }
}
```

How I am implementing it on my ViewController

```
let collectionView = DrawUI_mainCollectionView()
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check idUserintersctionEnabled is set on view and collection view

Comment: So I added: self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true to the setup function and also set it to the collectionview but I have the same result.

Comment: Where are you setting the frame for `collectionView`? Almost certainly the issue is that your actual `UICollectionView` is being draw outside the bounds of its superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is not using auto layout, if you will add auto layout for the items:

- view that contains the collectionView in viewController
- collectionView in the view

It should work, the implementation:

In ViewController:

```
   let collectionView = DrawUI_mainCollectionView()
   collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
   
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

Inside the view:

```
private func setup() {
    
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(kScreenWidth),height: 137)
    
    let offset = 120.0
    let collectionViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offset, width: Double(kScreenWidth), height: Double(kScreenHeight))
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: collectionViewFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    self.collectionView!.delegate = self
    self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "MealCategoryCell", bundle:Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    self.addSubview(self.collectionView!)
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView , attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I tried to mark it the answer but I dont have enough rep.  Thank you Mr Spring!

Comment: No problem, glad i could help